# How to Bind a specific field to json instead of model?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, json

I am using **Asp.net MVC5**.  The scenario is like I have a view which is bound to a model.

Now there is a textbox in the view which I don't want to be bound to model field but to a specific **json**.  The view is getting automatically bound to that field because of the declaration.

Is there any way we can stop a specific field from binding to view or to override this ?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.country, new { @class = "form-control input-lg"})
```

While populating this textbox I dont want values from model , I want from specific json which is available in javascript code , but when it posts back I want textbox to post to country field.

Comment: You cant bind to JSON. Use javascript to set the value instead.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am trying to , but somehow its getting overridden and model is taking precedence.

Comment: The only way it can get _overridden_ is by javascript (or when the user types in it) so there must be something wrong with your script

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of contuntry using javascript. As below

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

           var JsonObj = GetJson();

           $("#country").val(JsonObj.country)
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@Html.TextBox("country", new { @class = "form-control input-lg"})`. And populate the value of your input through JavaScript on client side from JSON object.